# Finding indices of all matches between two lists

Tags: r, list, matching

I need to take subsets from a list of documents based on a random sample. I know there are a lot of questions about matching on stackoverflow, but I didn't see one that addressed my question.

To demonstrate what I am looking for, suppose we have two vectors:

```
> A <- c(1,2,4,5,8,9)
> B <- c(1,3,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10)
```

The function I need is similar to doing

```
> 1 == B
> [1] T F F F F F F F F F F F F
```

That is, I need a function `f` such that

```
> f(A,B)
> [1] T F T T F T T F F F T T F
```

Any ideas? `match(B,A)` returns something similar to what I'm looking for, but not quite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as `B %in% A`...